# reStructuredText link in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, restructuredtext, docstring

If I have the following function in Python:

```
def _add_parameter(self, a):
    # do something
```

And I want to add a docstring to link to the above function using reStructuredText, I just need to add an underscore at the end of the function name like the following:

```
"""
The _add_parameter_ adds parameters.
"""
```

But instead of linking it to the function, I get a `cannot find declaration to go to` warning. How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you using Sphinx? Then see http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/domains.html

Comment: Yes, I am using Sphinx. So according to your link I should do :py:func:`_add_parameter` ?

Comment: It's a method, so probably `:py:meth:~ClassName.method_name`, but have a go and see what works

Answer (score 1):

The autodoc extension only documents non private members, i.e. members where the name does not start with an underscore. From the documentation:

```
.. autoclass:: Noodle
       :members:
    will document all non-private member functions and properties (that is,
    those whose name doesn’t start with _).
```

So, when autodoc tries to find the place to link to, it doesn't find it.

To override not documenting private members you can use `:private-members:`, but I cannot tell from experience if that works.However, it is generally preferred to only document the public interface.

Answer (score 0):

Since the formatting of the comments made me confused, here it is with proper formatting:

```py
class A:
    def foo(): ...

def bar(): ...

"""
:py:meth:`A.foo`
:py:func:`bar`
"""
```